# Function returns undefined instead of true/false

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using the `lazy` module to parse a file with user id's and check if a specific user is in it. The modCheck should return true/false, but instead it returns undefined.

```
var fs = require("fs");
var lazy = require("lazy");

function parseLineToString(line) {
    //checks to see if line is empty
    if (line == undefined) {
        return "";
    } else {
        return line.toString();
    }
}

function modCheck(channel, message) {
    var readStreamMC = fs.createReadStream("channel_mods/"+getChannelID(channel));
    //opens a read stream to a file depending on the string "channel"
    readStreamMC.on("end", function() {
        //after parsing all the lines, if it hasn't returned true, return false
        return false;
    });
    //using lazy to parse all the lines in a file
    new lazy(readStreamMC)
        .lines
        .forEach(function(line){
            //message.user is a 21 character user id
            if (parseLineToString(line).slice(0, 21) == message.user) {
                return true;
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: Those return values are only returning from the anonymous function scope and not the modCheck scope.

Comment: *"The isMod should return true/false, but instead it returns undefined"* Okay. Show us the code for `isMod` and maybe we can help.

Comment: ***sigh*** Another ask-and-run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the looks of it, your function "modCheck".. not "isMod"... is terminating/finishing before its inner loops/foreach are.

In this case, you can not do a simple return value.. As it will hit the last line of the modCheck function before it hits a return value...

Where you are returning true/false, You should call a function at this point which will handle the event of true/false...

Can show you example if needed, but simply change your lines of "return" to something more like "modCheckComplete(true)" and have a function called modCheckComplete to continue at the point where return would normally exit back to the calling code

```
var fs = require("fs");
var lazy = require("lazy");

function parseLineToString(line) {
    //checks to see if line is empty
    if (line == undefined) {
        return "";
    } else {
        return line.toString();
    }
}

function modCheck(channel, message) {
    var readStreamMC = fs.createReadStream("channel_mods/"+getChannelID(channel));
    //opens a read stream to a file depending on the string "channel"
    readStreamMC.on("end", function() {
        //after parsing all the lines, if it hasn't returned true, return false
        modCheckComplete(false);  /* CHANGED THIS */
    });
    //using lazy to parse all the lines in a file
    new lazy(readStreamMC)
        .lines
        .forEach(function(line){
            //message.user is a 21 character user id
            if (parseLineToString(line).slice(0, 21) == message.user) {
                modCheckComplete(true); /* CHANGED THIS */
            }
        });
}

/* ADDED THIS */
function modCheckComplete(bResult) {
    if (bResult==true) {
        alert('user successful');
    } else {
        alert('user failure');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Once a function uses an asynchronous processing block (like the `lazy` part) it's not possible to convert it back into a synchronous call (i.e. to "return" something to the caller).

The only thing you can do is accept an extra parameter or two with closures to call with the result or with the error, in other words you need to publish an asynchronous interface too.

Node.js for example provides a `readFileSync` beacuse it's impossible to build one given only `readFile`.